# How to make a <label> stretch the entire length of its container <p>?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in my html:

```
<li>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="is_selected"/>
        <img src="http://site.com/images/user44.png" alt=""/>
        <label for="is_selected">Bob Smith</label>
    </p>
</li>
```

When I render this, what happens is that there's a lot of white space to the right side of the label 'Bob Smith'. The user must click directly on 'Bob Smith' to toggle the checkbox, if he clicks to the right at the empty space, nothing happens.

How can I do it so the label 'Bob Smith' stretches to fill the entire space to the right?

I've tried: `width: 100%` on the label but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `label` a `display:inline-block;` and then set a `width` to fill the remainder of the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qWSas/

Comment: thanks for that!  Wonder if you could explain the reasoning behind why this is needed?

Comment: Sure.  Label is an inline element and will only stretch to the space provided by the text.  This CSS sets it to block status (but inline, so it doesn't force a new line).

Comment: which other elements need to be set specifically like this?

Comment: @Click Upvote. This page has a listing: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Comment: **-1** This relies on the assumption that image takes up exactly 10%.

Comment: @Eric. Pls read the answer more carefully! I said *then set a width to fill the remainder of the space*  The OP figures out the remaining width and adjusts accordingly.

Comment: @Jason: What if it's a fluid container?

Comment: @Jason: Why assume it's fixed? The jsfiddle itself is fluid!

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden`, along with floating controls.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/br84k/

```
label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 20px;
}

input, img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

Will give it a width of 100% unless otherwise specified.

EDIT:

Making the label a `block` level element with css does cause some validation errors I do think, as `block` level elements should not be placed in `<p />` tags. Consider an alternative for the `<p />` tag if you implement this, a `<div />` will do just fine here.

Comment: This will bump the name down a line.

Comment: That entirely depends on how he wants the output to look, based on the html provided, this seems the way to go though.

Comment: thanks, this worked but it would push the label to the next line and setting the width didn't have any effect, so I'm having to go with the other answer.